# How can I replace a specific element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write some code that would replace a certain number within a vector. So if the vector contains something like 12345 and someone decides to replace or change element [4] with a 0 it would write out to a file, 12340.

So far, with the code below, I end up only replacing the first number in the file. And using

```
theFile << newIn.at(count) << endl;
```

Instead of

```
theFile << *i << endl;
```

Does not seem to work.

How can I modify a specific vector element and then write the whole vector out to the file correctly?

```
//change/replace/delete
cout <<  "What would you like to replace it with?" << endl;
cin >> newIn;
fileInfo.at(count) = newIn;

//open
fstream theFile("numbers.txt");

//write changes
ofstream thefile;
for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = fileInfo.begin(); i != fileInfo.end(); i++)
{
    theFile << *i << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's `count`? Where and how does it get its value?

Comment: what's the error? did you tried to print it to screen? what is the result when you replace `fileInfo.at(count) = newIn;`? how is fileInfo declared?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - count is just an infringement number...the program reads the contents of a file one at a time and asks you if you want to replace that item or not. The count increments every time the user selects not to change the item. I figured that way I could keep track of where I was in the vector.

Comment: Your claim that "with the code below, I end up only replacing the first number in the file" suggests strongly that `count == 0`, not 4. Figure out why.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I'm happy to report that this was the error because it's simple enough to fix. Can you write it as an answer, so I can give you credit? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have two declarations of `theFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fileInfo[count] = newIn;

If that doesn't work, as a sanity check, you should double-check that you are reading in your vector correctly in the first place, and also use cout to print the state of the vector in addition to writing to your output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use the copy algorithm from the STL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
string fileName("resources\\data.txt");
ofstream outputFile(fileName);

vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
v[3] = 9;

copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(outputFile, ","));
```

The last parameter in copy has a separator which I've chosen to be a comma.  You can of course pass an empty string to exactly what you asked for.